# Flutter test find by sub text

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart

Is it possible to assert a test if the certain text is found either as full string match or as a sub string of other text?

I want the following test to pass as long as the string `Foo` is found anywhere, even as sub string of other strings. What should I change?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
void main() {
  testWidgets('Find sub text', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(Text('Error code is Foo', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr));
    expect(find.text('Error code is Foo'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('Foo'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

So far:

```
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _TextFinder:<zero widgets with text "Foo" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected
```

Comment: Hello, added a working answer.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `find.textContaining`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
void main() {
  testWidgets('Find sub text', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(Text('Error code is Foo', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr));
    expect(find.text('Error code is Foo'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.textContaining('Foo'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace:

```
expect(find.text('Foo'), findsOneWidget);
```

with:

```
expect(find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) {
  if (widget is Text) {
    final Text textWidget = widget;
    if (textWidget.data != null) return textWidget.data.contains('Foo');
    return textWidget.textSpan.toPlainText().contains('Foo');
  }
  return false;
}), findsOneWidget);
```

You will first find Text widget, then check for substring in the Text string

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find.textContaining](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/textContaining.html) to find a Text widget containing the string you're looking for.

This method has a property called `findRichText` that defaults to false so if the text you're looking for is in a RichText or TextSpan widget, you'll need to set this to true:

```
expect(find.textContaining('Error code is Foo', findRichText: true), findsOneWidget);
```